# What is the SQL operator name for "<>"?

Tags: sql, operators

I am confused and did not find in Google. Can anyone tell me What is `Sql <>` operator name?

Comment: Both <> and != are "not equals"

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`<>` is NOT Equal to, it's the same as `!=`

Comment: It's true that they are, functionally, the same.  However, how the SQL optimizer uses them is very different.  =/!= are simply evaluated as true/false whereas <> means the engine has to look and see if the value is greater than or less than, meaning more performance overhead.  Just something to consider when writing queries that may be expensive.

Comment: I don't believe that statement is correct, the operators are functionally equivalent, <> is not a combination of < and > it is a distinct operator in its own right, not equal to.  Why would the optimiser care if it was greater or less than the value? all it has to check is that it is not equal to something.

Comment: I've proven this in several stored procedures that we have.  It all depends on the indexes that exist on the table.  When you use <>, I believe the engine scans/seeks all values that are greater than or less than.  When we use !=, it simply goes for all values that don't equal what you defined.  We've seen performance gains from 30 mins to 3 mins on several of our procedures here.  Again, everyone's environments/indexes are different, but we try to avoid using <> operators on indexed columns as they are not SARGable.  See: http://www.sql-server-pro.com/sql-where-clause-optimization.html

Comment: @Kris If you look at an execution plan you will see they collapse to the same operator. Is it possible your performance differences were due to a new/different plan for other reasons? Could you demonstrate some proof on this question? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155650/authoritative-source-that-and-are-identical-in-performance

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer: here is a proof for SQL Server that your claim is wrong: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155670/1822 and here is another one for Postgres: the execution plan clearly shows that `!=` gets re-written to `<>` by the optimizer: http://rextester.com/CMEYC24808

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer You are mistaken. They are parsed into the same token. The engine doesn't have to do anything about less than or greater than to evaluate <>, and as it sees the same token for both it never even gets the chance. Clearly your 'proof' was invalid at some point.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer What Aaron is saying is that you may very well have experienced an improvement in speed one time upon changing only that operator; however, the difference may not have been because of the operator itself but because the query changing at all caused production of a new execution plan. (And you were having a parameter sniffing problem, for example.) It is flatly ridiculous to say that <> is not SARGable. Try it. Change all the != in your database to <> and see that it performs the same!

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer - RE: "I believe the engine scans/seeks all values that are greater than or less than" the fact that `!=/<>` can be converted to two range seeks is precisely what makes it sargable. Otherwise it would need to scan *all* rows and evaluate the predicate on all of them. Unless the value being excluded is common the difference between the two approaches is likely to be small however which is why some people just categorize not equals as unsargable and leave it at that.

Answer (score 7):

It's "not equal". Look in the list of operators for the database you're using, and find the appropriate section (usually "comparison operators"). For example:

- [SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020.aspx)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)
- [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm#i1004774)
- [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-comparison.html)

Answer (score 5):

It is the `not equals` operator. 
Usage:

```
select *  
from table
where foo <> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the Not Equal operator, but I am going to have to be verbose to get my answer posted because I haven't entered enough characters yet.

Answer (score 2):

`<>` means not equal same as `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true. (a <> b)  or (a != b) is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer – Technically there is no difference between != and <>. Both of them work the same way and there is absolutely no difference in terms of performance or result.
If != and <> both are the same, which one should be used in SQL queries?

You can use either != or <> both in your queries as both technically same but I prefer to use <> as that is SQL-92 standard.