# What is the meaning of <> in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that includes <> in it. I don't know the exact usage of it.

```
SELECT * FROM table_laef WHERE id = ? AND genre_type <> 'LIVE'
```

P.S.: Im sorry for this basic syntax, since I have searched for this on Google. All they give is about <=>. Thanks anyway, guys!

Comment: this means doesn't equal to the string 'LIVE'

Comment: literally, less than or greater than

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179419/what-is-the-sql-operator-name-for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the SQL operator name for "<>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179419/what-is-the-sql-operator-name-for)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`<>` is [Standard SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_SQL) and stands for *not equal* or `!=`.

Answer (score 12):

`<>` means **not equal to**, `!=` also means not equal to.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020.aspx)

Comment: `!=` is deprecated. Always use `<>`.

Comment: @jarlh I couldn't find any source where it says `!=` is deprecated. Please provide.

Comment: @evilReiko, that comment was written almost two years ago... I probably meant according to the ANSI/ISO SQL specification. And the question is tagged <mysql>, and this answer links to MS SQL Server. Anyway, AFAIK all dbms support `<>`, and probably most of them `!=`...

Comment: Which link shows `!=` being deprecated anywhere?

Answer (score 10):

`<>` means **NOT EQUAL TO**, `!=` also means **NOT EQUAL TO**. It's just another syntactic sugar. both `<>` and `!=` are same.

The below two examples are doing the same thing. Query publisher table to bring results which are **NOT EQUAL TO `<> !=`** USA.

`SELECT pub_name,country,pub_city,estd FROM publisher WHERE country <> "USA";`

`SELECT pub_name,country,pub_city,estd FROM publisher WHERE country != "USA";`

Comment: I'd think `<>` would mean 'greater than or less than' when it comes to a number, which is equivalent to 'not equal to', but I can't really see any reason for its existence in MySQL when `!=` already existed, unless it's there as a quicker keystroke alternative or for people that are used to `<>`. I'm guessing that's what's meant by 'syntactic sugar' in this context.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, I use `<>` to preferentially place specific rows at the front of a sort request.

For instance, under the column `topic`, I have the classifications of 'Chair', 'Metabolomics', 'Proteomics', and 'Endocrine'. I always want to list any individual(s) with the topic 'Chair', first, and then list the other members in alphabetical order based on their `topic` and then their `name_last`.

I do this with:

```
SELECT scicom_list ORDER BY topic <> 'Chair',topic,name_last;
```

This outputs the rows in the order of:
Chair
Endocrine
Metabolomics
Proteomics

Notice that `topic <> 'Chair'` is used to select all the rows with 'Chair' first. It then sorts the rows where `topic = Chair` by `name_last`.*

**This is a bit counterintuitive since `<>` equals `!=` based on other feedback in this post.*

This syntax can also be used to prioritize multiple categories. For instance, if I want to have "Chair" and then "Vice Chair" listed before the rest of the topics, I use the following

```
SELECT scicom_list ORDER BY topic <> 'Chair',topic <> 'Vice Chair',topic,name_last;
```

This outputs the rows in the order of:
Chair
Vice Chair
Endocrine
Metabolomics
Proteomics

Comment: This is a really innovative insight and I up voted you for passing along this pro-level knowledge! Kudos

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, `<>` means ***Not Equal To***, just like `!=`.

```
mysql> SELECT '.01' <> '0.01';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT .01 <> '0.01';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 'zapp' <> 'zappp';
        -> 1
```

see the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) for more info

Comment: @jarlh I'm not aware of some type of sql where `<>` doesn't mean **Not Equal To**. Is there any?

Comment: Wrong product, incomplete answer e.g. what about when one of the expressions' is null?

Comment: Detail is never a bad thing on SO. The problem is you've only given partial details i.e. you mention nonnull values but omit the other cases. And why mention `Transact-SQL` when the question is tagged `mySQL`? At least I give details when I downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

`<>` is equal to `!=` i.e, both are used to represent the NOT EQUAL operation. For instance, `email <> ''` and `email != ''` are same.

Comment: So `email <> ''` would return NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

I know im late to the game but maybe this will help somebody...
this is not true even though everyone wrote it
<> is equal to !=
it actually is less than or greater than
the exception is with NULL

column <> 3 will not get null columns
column != 3 will get null columns

hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, but neither <> nor != will return rows where the column being compared is null. Can you please supply a link to an authoritative source that says otherwise, or where you read that != is deprecated?